# treeview event DrawNode is not firing

Tags: c#, treeview

I want to change the colour of selected item in treeview even if the selected item is not focused. I am using DrawoNode mothed for this purpose. But my DrawNode event is not firing. What could be the problem? Here is my code:

```
SolidBrush greenBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);
    SolidBrush redBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);

    private void tvVouchers_DrawNode(object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Node.IsSelected)
        {
            if (tvVouchers.Focused)
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(greenBrush, e.Bounds);
            else
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(redBrush, e.Bounds);
        }
        else
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, e.Bounds);

        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(SystemPens.Control, e.Bounds);

        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics,
                               e.Node.Text,
                               e.Node.TreeView.Font,
                               e.Node.Bounds,
                               e.Node.ForeColor);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that the DrawNode property is set to OwnerDrawText or OwnerDrawAll, then the event will be fired.

*OnwerDrawText: 'The TreeNode label area can be customized. All other TreeNode elements are drawn automatically.'
OwnerDrawAll: 'The appearance of the entire TreeNode can be customized. Icons, check boxes, plus and minus signs, and lines connecting the nodes must be drawn manually if they are desired.'*